# Horizontal scroller in grid view

Tags: android

can anyone tell me a way to implement horizontal scroll in grid view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last i was able to implement horizontall scrolling grid view in android ... Here is the code:

```
public class HorizontalGridView extends Activity {
    Bitmap viewBgrnd;
    ImageButton img ;
    Button button;
    Button b1[] = new Button[100];
    static int total=0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        horizontalScrollGalleryLayout();
    }

    public void horizontalScrollGalleryLayout () {
        Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.image0,R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,R.drawable.image5,
            R.drawable.image6,R.drawable.image7,R.drawable.image8,
            R.drawable.image9,R.drawable.image10,R.drawable.image11,
            R.drawable.image12,R.drawable.image13,R.drawable.image14,
            R.drawable.image15,R.drawable.image16,R.drawable.image17,
            R.drawable.image18,R.drawable.image19,R.drawable.image20,
            R.drawable.image21,R.drawable.image22,R.drawable.image23,
            R.drawable.image24,R.drawable.image25,R.drawable.image26,
            R.drawable.image27,R.drawable.image28,R.drawable.image29,
            R.drawable.image30,R.drawable.image31,R.drawable.image32,
            R.drawable.image33,R.drawable.image34,R.drawable.image35,
            R.drawable.image36,R.drawable.image37,R.drawable.image38,
            R.drawable.image39,R.drawable.image40,R.drawable.image41,
            R.drawable.image42,R.drawable.image43,R.drawable.image44,
            R.drawable.image45,R.drawable.image46,R.drawable.image47,
            R.drawable.image48,R.drawable.image49,R.drawable.image50,
            R.drawable.image51,R.drawable.image52,R.drawable.image53,
            R.drawable.image54,R.drawable.image55,R.drawable.image56,
            R.drawable.image57,R.drawable.image58,R.drawable.image59,
            R.drawable.image60,R.drawable.image61,R.drawable.image62,
            R.drawable.image63,R.drawable.image64,R.drawable.image65,
            R.drawable.image66,R.drawable.image67,R.drawable.image68,
            R.drawable.image69,R.drawable.image70,R.drawable.image71,
            R.drawable.image72,R.drawable.image73,R.drawable.image74,
            R.drawable.image75,R.drawable.image76,R.drawable.image77,
            R.drawable.image77,R.drawable.image79,R.drawable.image8,
            R.drawable.image81,R.drawable.image82,R.drawable.image83,
            R.drawable.image84,R.drawable.image85,R.drawable.image86,
            R.drawable.image87,R.drawable.image88,R.drawable.image89,
            R.drawable.image90,R.drawable.image91,R.drawable.image92,
            R.drawable.image93,R.drawable.image94,R.drawable.image95,
            R.drawable.image96,R.drawable.image97,R.drawable.image98,
            R.drawable.image99,
        };
        HorizontalScrollView sv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
        LinearLayout llh = new LinearLayout(this);
        llh.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsTV = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsLL = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsLLD = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        for(int k=0;k<mThumbIds.length;k++)
        {   
            LinearLayout llv = new LinearLayout(this);
            for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
                llv.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                button = new Button(this);
                try {
                    button.setBackgroundResource(mThumbIds[total]);
                    total++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                llv.addView(button, layoutParamsTV);
                //b1[k].setBackgroundResource(mThumbIds[k]);
            }

            //llv.addView(button, layoutParamsTV);
            llh.addView(llv, layoutParamsLL);
            llh.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }

        sv.addView(llh, layoutParamsLLD);
        setContentView(sv);
        sv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, acceptable for small-sized collections, but please do not call this a GridView. It lacks an Adapter that lets you display things without spending several seconds inflating all the views and filling up your memory with hundreds of Bitmaps at once.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the property [android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3ascrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack)

Comment: i cant see the result i wanted. Actually i have a grid view , it is scrolling vertically, but i want it to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Actually what i found out is that implementing horizontal scroll in grid view is not possible. Rather we can implement a relative layout inside Horizontal scroll view and keep our widgets under it.

Comment: Very well. I suggest that you answer your question yourself, and then I delete my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Horizontal scroller in grid view problem are solved here by an alternative way. Thare are used button in every grid view in Horizontal scroll view.